# Django order_by a related model's method

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'd like to order an "Event" queryset by "distance" for each individual query

Given the following, how can I pull it off?

```
class Venue(models.Model):
    latitude = models.FloatField(max_length=10)
    longitude = models.FloatField(max_length=10)

    def distance(self, query_coordinates):
        "Calculates distance on a query by query basis"
        venue_coords = self.latitude, self.longitude
        distance_to_venue = distance.distance(query_coordinates, house_coords) # a function which outputs distance in miles
        return distance_to_venue

class Event(models.Model):
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, related_name='shows')
```

I've been pouring over the annotate docs after reading some related stackoverflow questions, but can't figure out how to get it to work for my situation. How can I do this efficiently??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pull it off, django doesn't support ordering by model methods.

For working with geo-spatial data try GeoDjango (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/).